# I included StlLock.h in my .h file and got these errors

Tags: c++

Ok, so I just installed Visual Studio yesterday and was just minding my own business trying to make a learn C++/wasting time. I ran the code you're about to see a few times without issue and then I included the StlLock.h file, then I happened upon this error list.

[Error list in my Visual Studio along with the "problematic" code, I guess.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qL7Vh.png)

The errors vanish as soon as I remove StlLock.h.
As far as I recall I did not touch StlLock.h at all. Is there just something wrong with it?
Also, I'm pretty new to programming and C++. I'm trying to teach myself but got caught up in this.

The full code is in 2 files:

### ABLASAN.cpp

```
#include "ABLASAN.h"

int main()
{
    Math test;
    
    test.Show_Atributes();
    test.radijus = 4;
    std::cout << test.Area(test.radijus) << "\n";
    std::cin.get();
}
```

### ABLASAN.h

```
#pragma once
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <StlLock.h>
#include <cmath>

constexpr double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;


class Math{
    public:

    double radijus, x_os, y_os;

    Math(){
        x_os = 0;
        y_os = 0;
        radijus = 0;
    }

    double Area(double x, double y)
    {
        return x * y;
    }
    double Area(double r)
    {
        return pow(r, 2) * PI;
    }
    void Show_Atributes() {
        std::cout << "X-os: " << x_os << "\nY-os: " << y_os << "\nRadijus: " << radijus << std::endl;
    }
};
```

P.S.
Just as a side-note: I used the cmath file and read somewhere that that file has defined mathematical constants using this:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
    std::cout << M_PI << " " << M_E << " " << M_SQRT2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I can't seem to get that to work.

**I'm using the Visual Studio C++20 compiler just in case it's important. Also, I did not change any project settings/properties/anything.**

Thanks to everyone and anyone in advance.
Also, I'm deeply sorry if this was already answered somewhere. I just didn't find it before writing this up.

Comment: `StlLock.h` uses MS-Windows API. The code needs `#include <windows.h>` to get these definitions.  Also why were you including `StlLock.h` ? And please post all code and errors as text in the question.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thank you very much for the quick answer! You're completely right, the moment I include `windows.h` the error list dissapears, but only if included _before_ `StlLock.h`. Does not work if included _after_.

Comment: That's because the file is part of the Windows SDK and not a Standard C++ header.  Unless you are doing specific low level Windows API programming you should not be including it.